# Is it optimize to have all parameteres in XML file?

Tags: java, xml, parameters, configuration, jpos

I'm recently using JPOS to simulate financial transactions based on ISO 8583.
I noticed in JPOS they love using XML a lot of files as configuration parameters.
I have a question in my mind that why they choose this approach?
I want to develop a bigger application which can work with a lot of Servers/Terminals/Transaction/Databases/External Peers(Based On TCP/IP over ISO-8583)/A lot of parameters in DB
when I tried to imagine such a software with JPOS, I came to a big deploy folder with a lot of critical files which is hard to configure and needs migration from Records in tables to XML tags.
My question is Why they use file system to store configurations and is it a good idea to use that many XML files or should I make changes in my software and let it read configurations from DB?(as it is easier to manages Backup/Modify/Archive/Manage Authorizes and stuff in DB)

Comment: "My question is Why they use file system to store configurations" - I guess only *they* can tell you exactly. We can only speculate. One Idea would be it is just a XML-Serialization of some configuration-object. Seems hacky to me, but who am I to judge. If it works well, then why not? If it seems unfeasable for **your** application - then don't do it. There are arguments for DB-Config and XML as well as against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at jpos history, xml configuration has been available from the very beginning and the project is pretty old but still very very active. There are arguments of for and against  DB v/s XML configuration.

Yes the configuration files can get out of hand for larger projects. Having said that, some of the configuration can be manipulated using freemarker templates or ant parameter substitution at build time or have use a component like [sysconfigconfigurationfactory](http://jpos.org/blog/2012/05/jpos-ee-sysconfigconfigurationfactory/) which can give you an example of pulling the configuration from a table.
Migrating existing systems are not always easy, you could run scripts to generate the xml files from your existing configuration and save them, nothing stops you.
Changing config files and saving them does hot swap the config and make it available for use immediately. The numbering of files provides the order of loading components and handling dependencies (can be a pain too).
Other runtime configurations can be done using regular DB access via hibernate.